# IE ActiveX control for internet explorer 6.0 on Windows 7

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-6, activex, browser

> I have a managed application which has
>   a web browser component. I am trying
>   to write a program which automatically
>   fills some HTML text fields , set some
>   HTML combo boxes, click buttons... I have done these sort of things. The
>   program supposed to upload some excel
>   files to a remote server. The excel
>   files are attached to an HTML form. That is the point I am stacked at.
>
> I know this issue has been talked on
>   SO but I am stucked at the point of
>   setting this famous html element
>   type=file . I dig in the forums and
>   web about this situation. I read that
>   with IE 6.0 ActiveX wrapper , one can
>   manage to set file chooser HTML
>   element by Send.SendKeys() security hole.

My question is:

> In my recent code I am using a wrapper
>   class which I found here :
>   http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2008/09/18/newwindow2-events-in-the-c-webbrowsercontrol.aspx
>   since IE 8.0 is installed on my win7 I am automatically wrapping IE 8.0. Is it possible to wrap IE 6.0
>   on .NET 4.0 and on windows 7 and IS IT
>   POSSIBLE TO SOMEHOW VIRTUALIZE YOUR
>   PROGRAM FOR JUST USING IE 6.0 SINCE
>   THE USER OF THE PROGRAMS MAY NOT WANT
>   TO INSTALL IE 6.0. And I did not try
>   this; Is it possible to set the
>   filechooser text field with IE 6.0.
>   And Where can I get IE 6.0 ?

If someone helps , I assure that I pray for him/her to the rest of my entire life.
Thanks.

note:any comment if my path is wrong from the beginning , would be very appreciated... thanks again.

Comment: There's no supported way to do this, no.

Comment: Ok now I can sleep well since I got a minus on the question. Now I know my path is wrong. I will use System.NET classes to the automation. WebBrowser can be a good automation tool exception of file chooser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A security hole is not a feature, it is a bug. Don't rely on the existance of a bug.
I think this hole is fixed in all modern versions of manjor browsers, so if you embed an open source webbrowser into your solution you need to find a very old one (e.g. FireFox 1.5).

Answer (score 1):

Why wrap IE 6 to automate this when you can achieve the same result by using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)?

Comment: can I rule over file chooser textbox with this tool.

Comment: Yes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707884/selenium-rc-how-to-upload-file-using-attachfile